# Trying to parse XML with attribute and map key values in a Map

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have to parse an XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <contentType>Document</contentType>
    <siteName>mySite</siteName>
    <listName>myLib</listName>
    <folderName>docset-folder</folderName>
    <documentSetName>documentSet</documentSetName>
    <fields>
        <field name="META_1">123456789</field>
        <field name="META_2">Someone</field>
        <field name="META_3">Germany</field>
        <field name="META_4">Abonnement2 LC</field>
    </fields>
</data>
```

I created a simple POJO class for mapping this XML. I set properties of the XML file.
Concerning the field, I can have as many data with unique name.

```
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "data")
public class MetaDataSharePoint {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "contentType")
    private String contentType;
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private String siteName;
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private String listName;
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private String folderName;
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private String documentSetName;
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "fields")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "field")
    private Map<String, Object> fields;
}
```

My objective is to map correctly this XML and handle a POJO. The following code allow to open an XML file and read its content. The XMLMapper object allows to match the xml and the object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, XMLStreamException, TransformerException {
    String path = "src/test/resources/bill.xml";
    XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLStreamReader sr = f.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path));
    XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();

    sr.next();
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    MetaDataSharePoint metaDataSharePoint = mapper.readValue(sr, MetaDataSharePoint.class);

    // start test
    System.out.println(metaDataSharePoint);
    System.out.println("contentType : " + metaDataSharePoint.getContentType());
    System.out.println("DocumentSetName : " + metaDataSharePoint.getDocumentSetName());
    System.out.println("ListName : " + metaDataSharePoint.getListName());
    System.out.println("SiteName : " + metaDataSharePoint.getSiteName());
    System.out.println("FolderName : " + metaDataSharePoint.getFolderName());
    metaDataSharePoint.getFields().forEach((key, value) -> {
        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println(value);
    });
    // end test

    sr.close();
}
```

I successfully map part of my object.
I print the following:

```
MetaDataSharePoint(contentType=Document, siteName=mySite, listName=myLib, folderName=docset-folder, documentSetName=documentSet, fields={field={name=META_4, =Abonnement2 LC}})
contentType : Document
DocumentSetName : documentSet
ListName : myLib
SiteName : mySite
FolderName : docset-folder
field
{name=META_4, =Abonnement2 LC}
```

My map is not returning the expected results. I would like to add to a map keys and values.
I would expect something like this:

```
key: META_1
value: 123456789

key: META_2
value: Someone

...
```

I tried using several methods to map this XML unsuccesfully.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simple modified my POJO :

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@XmlRootElement(name = "data")
public class MetaDataSharePoint {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "contentType")
    private String contentType;
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private String siteName;
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private String listName;
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private String folderName;
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private String documentSetName;
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private List<MetaDataFields> fields;
}
```

I replaced the Map with a list of objects. For this I implemented this POJO :

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "field")
public class MetaDataFields {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String name;
    @JacksonXmlText
    private String value;
}
```

I retrieve the data as I expect. that's cool...